# I cannot read second internal HD

Tags: mount, drive

I reformatted my Win "C" drive and loaded Ubuntu 11.04. The second internal HD of course is not read.  It is shown in 'disk utility'.  I try to mount it in disk utility but I get an error message

```
error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sda1 is already mounted on /
```

One problem I see is the error relates to sda1, but I am trying to mount sdb.

Unfortunately, I am windows literate and ignorant of the coding for linux.

Can someone help me with the code to mount my second drive (sdb)

Nathan

Answer (score 1):

Before you can mount a disk, you need to have a mountpoint (which is a directory). The general command for mounting a partition is:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt
```

Here, `/dev/sdb1` is the first (`1`) partition on the second disk (`b`). If the command was succesful, the filesystem wil be available at `/mnt`. Only the superuser can mount new filesystems, therefore `sudo` is prepended on the command. If you're mounting multiple partitions, you might want to create a folder before use:

```
sudo mkdir /media/mountp
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/mountp
```

Do not forget to remove the directory after unmounting it:

```
sudo umount /media/mountp
sudo rmdir /media/mountp
```

Comment: I  used the command....sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt.....I (enter) and I am prompted for my password.  After the password (I know it doesn't show on the screen) nothing has changed.  The drive does not show in (computer).  I reboot and still no show.

Comment: @Nathan it doesn't show in (computer) because you didn't mount it in a directory under /media.  Look in /mnt and your files should be there.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: `ls /mnt` shows the contents of the `/mnt` folder. If you are not familiar with the command line, I suggest you to mount the directory through a file manager like Nautilus (or open the disk by opening *Places*)